# Error when running library(ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just updated to R 2.11.1 and after installing ggplot2, I tried

```
library(ggplot2)
```

and got

```
Loading required package: proto
Loading required package: grid Loading
required package: reshape Loading
required package: plyr Loading
required package: digest Error in
eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not
find function "proto" In addition:
Warning message: In library(package,
lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only =
TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :  
there is no package called 'proto'
Error : unable to load R code in
package 'ggplot2' Error:
package/namespace load failed for
'ggplot2'
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `install.packages("proto")` after getting this?

Comment: You are probably missing the `proto` package. Have you tried to install it?

Comment: My experience was that library(ggplot2) loaded fine but a call to ggsave() would generate an error about 'digest' as a missing package.  The solution below fixed my issue as well.

Comment: Related post: [How should I deal with “package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)” warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)` would do the trick... install `proto` package

Answer (score 22):

Open R shell and type following in it

```
install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)
```

then it will ask you to select the mirror, select closest one and it will install it and solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Also have had troubles, when installing ggplots2, but here is a curious solution (tested on windows):

- I installed via RStudio. Both from Tools->install packages and by typing `install.packages("ggplots2", dep=T)`. It didn't work because it kept not installing the dependencies.
- I then installed direct by R gui `install.packages("ggplots2", dep=T)` and everything went well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this did the trick.

1. Install the `lazyeval` package.
2. Then install `ggplot2`
3. Load the `ggplot2` library and everything will hopefully work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Steps
1.Go To -> Tools
2.Click -> Install Packages
3.In Packages Text Box Type ggplot2
Check the checkbox & install dependencies

And your good to go !