# How to install the aruleviz R Package?

Tags: r

I have been trying to install the aruleviz R package but I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arulesViz’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘gplots’
```

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This sometimes happens when a dependency fails to be detected or installed properly. Try to install gplots manually and then install arulesViz.

Comment: can you try to install gplots, install.packages("gplots")

Comment: Possible dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134020/error-when-running-libraryggplot2 (and most links found within https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+there%20is%20no%20package%20called)